# How can I group hash contents based on key starts_with?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a hash that currently looks like this:

```rb
{
  "prefix1_key1": [a, b],
  "prefix1_key2": [c, d],
  "prefix2_key1": [e, f],
  "prefix3_key1": [g, h]
}
```

And I would want to transfer this into:

```rb
{
  "prefix1": [a, b, c, d],
  "prefix2": [e, f],
  "prefix3": [g, h]
}
```

Is there any clean way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
hash = {
  "prefix1_key1": [a, b],
  "prefix1_key2": [c, d],
  "prefix2_key1": [e, f],
  "prefix3_key1": [g, h]
}

hash.each_with_object({}) do |ary, result| 
 key = ary[0].to_s.split('_')[0]
 (result[key] ||= []).concat(ary[1]) 
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can avoid producing nested arrays in the first place by using `Array#concat` or similar.

Comment: @razvans: you don't need flatten now :)

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
hash = {
  "prefix1_key1": ['a', 'b'],
  "prefix1_key2": ['c', 'd'],
  "prefix2_key1": ['e', 'f'],
  "prefix3_key1": ['g', 'h']
}
```

Code

```
p hash.group_by { |k, v| k.to_s.split("_").first }
      .transform_values { |x| x.flat_map(&:pop) }
```

Output

```
{"prefix1"=>["a", "b", "c", "d"], "prefix2"=>["e", "f"], "prefix3"=>["g", "h"]}
```